# SQL query takes too much time to execute

Tags: sql

I have a problem with a query that take too much time to execute. The query is:

```
SELECT id, name 
  FROM user 
 WHERE id IN ( SELECT DISTINCT ( user_id ) 
                 FROM `webchat` 
                WHERE closed = 0 )
```

**webchat.closed** and **user.id** are indexs. The query takes 6 seconds to complete.

But if I do this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ( user_id ) 
  FROM `webchat` 
 WHERE closed = 0
```

It only takes 0.00002 seconds to complete. It returns two results, 16023 and 14020. And if I do this query:

```
SELECT id, name FROM user WHERE id IN (16023, 14020)
```

only takes 0.00004 seconds to complete.

So, why the first query takes 6 seconds to finish?

Comment: USe a join instead of an IN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user.id, user.name 
  FROM user INNER JOIN `webchat` on user.id = `webchat`.user_id
 WHERE `webchat`.closed = 0
```

Comment: This could return duplicate values if thee is more than one matching record in `webchat`.

Answer (score 1):

This is your query:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name
FROM user u
WHERE u.id IN ( SELECT DISTINCT ( user_id ) FROM webchat WHERE closed = 0 )
```

First, the `distinct` is redundant in the subquery.  Second, many databases handle `exists` better than `in`.  Try this:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name
FROM user u
WHERE EXISTS (select 1 from webchat wc where wc.closed = 0 and wc.user_id = u.id);
```

An index will help this query.  Try the composite index `webchat(user_id, closed)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, name 
FROM user 
INNER JOIN `webchat` on `webchat`.user_id = user.id and `webchat`.closed = 0
```